# Finding the direction of touchDragInside sent event on UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, events, optimization, uibutton

A `UIButton` has a sent event acton `touchDragInside` (Touch Drag Inside). The button can be connected to a number of actions, for example:

```
@IBAction func dragButton(sender: UIButton) {
    ...
}
```

An answer should focus on determining drag direction, left, right, up, down, in Swift coding.

There's not a whole lot of information in the developer notes: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrolevents/1618240-touchdraginside

---

**Question:**

**How can I determine the actual drag direction when I tap and drag on a `UIButton` for the sent event action `touchDragInside`?**

Comment: you can specify different functions to be called for each `UIControlEvent`, so you know exactly what happened. Or you rather have a property on some `UIButton` subclass what tells you what was the latest control event?

Comment: I think I prefer an action, a `touchDragInside` action on the `UIButton`. The I just want to find the direction of that `touchDragInside` whether it is up, down, left or right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get 'Touch Drag Inside' Distance When Setting IBAction From Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27469731/get-touch-drag-inside-distance-when-setting-ibaction-from-storyboard)

Comment: Thanks, that focuses on distance. Instead I'm for an answer focusing on direction, left, right, up, down. Looking for a complete Swift 2 and 3 coding answer.

Comment: Do you want to track *all* `touchDragInside` events? Or only if the "drag" *began* inside the button? You will most likely need to implement one of the other events (such as `touchDown` or `touchDragEnter`) to save the **start** position, then compare that to the **new** position to determine drag direction.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted a complete answer to my own question. Hopefully it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: @chedabob not a duplicate. Different aims, different goals, different question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have an answer. Possibly not the most pretty code, but it works well.

**What to do:**

1. Simply drop a `UIButton` onto the Storyboard in a new Xcode project.
2. Drop the Swift 2 code below into the ViewController.swift file.
3. Connect the `UIButton` `touchDown` and `touchDragInside` actions to the corresponding code.
4. Tap Run ► in Xcode to start the Simulator.
5. Once the app is running, tap and drag on the `UIButton` to get a print out of the drag direction.

**Code:**

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var touchDragInsideLocationX: CGFloat!
    var touchDragInsideLocationX1: CGFloat!
    var touchDragInsideLocationX2: CGFloat!
    var touchDragInsideLocationX3: CGFloat!

    var touchDragInsideLocationY: CGFloat!
    var touchDragInsideLocationY1: CGFloat!
    var touchDragInsideLocationY2: CGFloat!
    var touchDragInsideLocationY3: CGFloat!

    @IBAction func touchDownAction(sender: AnyObject, event: UIEvent) {

        // Reset X location points
        touchDragInsideLocationX = 0
        touchDragInsideLocationX1 = 0
        touchDragInsideLocationX2 = 0
        touchDragInsideLocationX3 = 0

        // Reset Y location points
        touchDragInsideLocationY = 0
        touchDragInsideLocationY1 = 0
        touchDragInsideLocationY2 = 0
        touchDragInsideLocationY3 = 0
    }

    @IBAction func touchDragInsideAction(sender: AnyObject, event: UIEvent) {

        // Get current touchDragInside X and Y location points
        let button = sender as? UIButton
        let touch = (event.touchesForView(button!)?.first)! as UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInView(button)
        touchDragInsideLocationX = location.x
        touchDragInsideLocationY = location.y

        // Array previous touchDragInside X location points
        touchDragInsideLocationX3 = touchDragInsideLocationX2
        touchDragInsideLocationX2 = touchDragInsideLocationX1
        touchDragInsideLocationX1 = touchDragInsideLocationX

        // Array previous touchDragInside Y location points
        touchDragInsideLocationY3 = touchDragInsideLocationY2
        touchDragInsideLocationY2 = touchDragInsideLocationY1
        touchDragInsideLocationY1 = touchDragInsideLocationY

        // Determine touchDragInside X and Y velocity
        let touchDragInsideVelocityX = abs(touchDragInsideLocationX - touchDragInsideLocationX3)
        let touchDragInsideVelocityY = abs(touchDragInsideLocationY - touchDragInsideLocationY3)

        // Determine touchDragInside direction
        if touchDragInsideVelocityX > touchDragInsideVelocityY {
            if touchDragInsideLocationX3 != 0 {
                let touchDragInsideVelocityX = (touchDragInsideLocationX3 - touchDragInsideLocationX1)
                if touchDragInsideVelocityX > 0 {touchDragInsideLeft()} else {touchDragInsideRight()}
            }
        } else {
            if touchDragInsideLocationY3 != 0 {
                let touchDragInsideVelocityY = (touchDragInsideLocationY3 - touchDragInsideLocationY1)
                if touchDragInsideVelocityY > 0 {touchDragInsideUp()} else {touchDragInsideDown()}
            }
        }
    }

    func touchDragInsideLeft() {
        print("Left")
    }

    func touchDragInsideRight() {
        print("Right")
    }

    func touchDragInsideUp() {
        print("Up")
    }

    func touchDragInsideDown() {
        print("Down")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@user4806509 - Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I am happy that I was on the right track and didn't have to re-invent this wheel!

Two very minor changes for Swift 4 Xcode 9:

```
let touch = (event.touchesForView(button!)?.first)! as UITouch
```

...has been renamed, this now works:

```
let touch = (event.touches(for: button!)?.first)!   as UITouch
```

Also,

```
let location = touch.locationInView(button)
```

...has been renamed, this now works:

```
let location = touch.location(in: button)
```

Answer (score 0):

I previously posted above, but since then I have discovered (not here) that UIKit actually provides this exact functionality.

There are several gesture recognizers which detect pinch, swipe, pan, etc. These two address the original question:

- Swipe Gesture Recognizer - in the inspector, set it to detect one of:
  Up, Down, Left, or Right swipe (add multiple recognizers for second, third and
  fourth direction recognition)
- Pan Gesture Recognizer (see above)

I dragged these onto buttons and also onto views in the UI (works great and is an elegant solution). After dragging one of these, you have to set the specific direction of a (for example) swipe. Then you control-drag from the recognizer to the view controller code to define your needed IBAction functions.

Here is basic code for UP and DOWN swipe recognition:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBOutlet var textfield: UITextField!

    @IBAction func   UP(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        textfield.text = "BUTTON was swiped UP"
    }
    @IBAction func DOWN(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        textfield.text = "BUTTON was swiped DOWN"
    }

    @IBAction func UPview(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        textfield.text = "VIEW was swiped UP"
 }
    @IBAction func DOWNview(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        textfield.text = "VIEW was swiped DOWN"
    }
}
```